# why .NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans

My maven project uses spring, hibernate. I get "no such method error". I believe it is due to some conflict in version in dependencies but dont know what.
The build is successful. But during "NetBeans: Deploying on GlassFish Server 4.0" (i use the run button in Netbeans), i get below error which i have tried hard to eliminate without success. Any assistance is appreciated...

```
failed on GlassFish Server 4.0 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V.
```

Below i my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>AttestationSpring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description></description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- === -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- === -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- === -->
       <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4.2</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.183949</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.1.RELEASE
        </org.springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv4ee7</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>
    <name>AttestationSpring3HibernateMaven</name>
</project>
```

Below is my spring-servlet.xml where datasource, sessionfactory configurations are made..

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" 
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.attestation.entities" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
        <!--====== 

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
            -->
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I have read `.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V. Please see server.log for more details.` is due to conflicting jars/dependencies. But i dont know what is conflicting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem originated when i adapted the project from a working maven+spring+hibernate project. In a zealous attempt, i updated the pom.xml with all the latest versions of dependencies which i think led to the problem. But why it leads to problem, i am not sure. But for now, i have reverted to the original working (but older) versions of dependencies in pom.xml and everything has started working fine. Thanks for your assistance & efforts.

Comment: This is a common problem with Maven and all the dependancy complexity and duplicate JAR instances it adds.  

gerardribas is correct about the cause.  One of your libs is calling a method signature that is not present it the version of the Spring Core JAR you are using.  You would need to look at the Stack Trace to try and figure out which JAR is out of sync with your Spring Core JAR.

Your if you Maven Tool set shows you the complete (with children listed) dependency list you can go though it and usually find the one that is listed with multiple versions.

Answer (score 5):

Check if all jars of Spring Framework has the same version. I had this problem before and  it occurs because one dependency of spring framework was in other version number.

You can check the conflicts using maven console:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Comment: If you see my pom.xml i had posted above, i use `<version>${org.springframework.version}</version>` . so i am safe that way and there is no version conflict.

Comment: The problem originated when `i adapted the project from a working maven+spring+hibernate project`. In a zealous attempt, `i updated the pom.xml with all the latest versions of dependencies which i think led to the problem`. But why it leads to problem, i am not sure. But for now, `i have reverted to the original working (but older) versions of dependencies in pom.xml and everything has started working fine`. Thanks for your assistance & efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If text file encoding of your project is "Cp1252", change it to "UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

Just had one of our junior developers here had a very similar error with a spring boot app. Turns out IntelliJ was messed up, we quit IntelliJ, deleted the ".idea" folder within the project, and re-opened. Things worked just fine after that.

It seems that there must have been some caching that IntelliJ was doing to either store libraries or resolve dependencies. And somehow that cache got corrupted.

I know that the original post mentioned NetBeans (not IntelliJ) but I figured leaving this answer here might help. I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score -1):

yes, try to add all the jars of same version , and check whether all jars are added successfully to run Spring code .I also had same problem than i removed the different version jar files and it worked for me!

Comment: How do you "add all the jars of same version" in the maven example?

Comment: well i have run a simple spring+java project not maven ,thats all i can help.